# How to extract a frequency from a signal

Tags: filter, frequency, extract

Is there a simple way to extract the main frequency/period from a signal (without resorting to the FFT)?

For my requirements, this can result in either a value for the main frequency (e.g. 3Hz) or a value representing the strength of a target frequency. For example, in the following 1-D signal the frequency is about 4Hz, assuming the sampling rate is 50ms.

How can this be extracted from the data programmatically?

10
2
1
2
8
10
8
2
1
1
8
10
7
1
1
2
7
10
5
1

Answer (score 3):

Use Auto Correlation !

```
%using Matlab

%convert sample rate to hertz

fs = 1/(50/1000) % result = 20hz

vector = [10 2 1 2 8 10 8 2 1 1 8 10 7 1 1 2 7 10 5 1];

R = xcorr(vector);

[pks,locs]=findpeaks(R);

%result in hertz

fs./(diff(locs))

ans =

3.3333    4.0000    3.3333    3.3333    4.0000    3.3333

max(fs./diff(locs))

ans =

4
```

- Apply [Autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) on the signal, you can find a lot of
  source code in the web in defferent languages to do autocorrelation, a pseudo code:

  ```
  TotalSamples = length(signal)
  for z=1:TotalSamples
   sum = 0;

   for i=1:TotalSamples

             sum = sum + (signal(i)*signal(i + pos));

   end

   Xcorre(z) = Xcorre(z) + sum;
  end
  ```
- Find all local peaks from result of autocorrelation
- Compute the difference between local peaks `locs[k+1] - locs[k]`
- Divide your frame rate by the difference between local peaks
- The Frequency is the Maximum value

Comment: Thanks, just picked this up. I don't have matlab so was not able to run or follow your code. Do you have more details of the form of the algorithm for computing this?

Comment: but autocorrelation methods works only when there is  deterministic component right?there there is several components,then determine frequencies using auctocorrelation and this method is it still valid?

Comment: @datodatuashvili i'm sorry for delay i never saw your comment before, OW yeah is valid, the best algorithms in time domain to find pitch/frequencies are based in autocorrelation :-)